Finding edges after Separate


After using Separate, I want to find the edges between them, and I specifically want the ability to select them in any piece, not create a spline between them.
I want to pass the necessary selected vertexes to Attributes.





You can find doubled edges by proximity:

Or you can find the boundary between separated faces, save it, and only then separate:

I'm still using 2 "Extrude Mesh" nodes there, because I treat the "Join Geometry" as just the way to show both geometries at once:


I have added the image above.
I tried the first option, I have all the vertexes saved to attributes, and the Equal check doesn't work as it should. Maybe it has to do with Blender versions, I don't know.
The second option doesn't work for me either, it doesn't save anything to attributes at all.

@BlakJul domains matter, saving to vertices is not the same as saving to edges. The same goes for value types, saving to float is not the same as saving to boolean...

I added the image above.
I tried doing it two ways, but with Edge - Bool, same thing, also doesn't work
